# Choregraphe position Pepper

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

I would like to teach a location to Pepper and when I move it close to that location, he would get there.
But it would be best if there was a way to create positions that would move from one to another.

I tried this code [from the documentation](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-vision/allocalization/allocalization-0#allocalization-tuto) and I do not understand
how to have access that location again after saving in this example.

```
et = localizationProxy.learnHome()
# Check that no problem occurred.
if ret == 0:
  print "Learning OK"
else:
  print "Error during learning " + str(ret)

# Make some moves.
motionProxy.moveTo(0.5, 0.0, 0.2)

# Go back home.
ret = localizationProxy.goToHome()
# Check that no problem occurred.
if ret == 0:
  print "go to home OK"
else:
  print "error during go to home " + str(ret)

# Save the data for later use.
ret = localizationProxy.save("example")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ALLocalization.load("example")`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-vision/allocalization/allocalization-api#ALLocalizationProxy::load__ssCR) to reload the map.

The APIs `learnHome` / `goToHome` are a particular case of a more general mechanism. If you want to learn several locations to move to, use [`ALLocalization.getRobotPosition`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-vision/allocalization/allocalization-api#ALLocalizationProxy::getRobotPosition__b) and save them into files under [your app's writeable path](http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/api/python/path.html#qi.path.userWritableDataPath). To go to these locations, once you have reloaded the map and these locations, tranform the position according to the current robot location, and use [`ALNavigation.navigateTo`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-motion/alnavigation/alnavigation-api#ALNavigationProxy::navigateTo__floatCR.floatCR) to go there.

You can use the [`ALNavigation`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-motion/alnavigation/exploration-api#exploration-api) APIs instead of `ALLocalization`, but it is lacking a tutorial.

I was told SLAM in NAOqi 2.5 is not working well and that [in 2.9, using the Qi SDK](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/movement/tuto/extend_map_tutorial.html#extend-map-tutorial), it works much more reliably.